# Merge Sort List Implementation TopDown + BottomUp + Abstract MergeSort

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement a Merge Sort for static lists (ArrayLists). I have both the TopDown and the BottomUp implementation. However, I believe that the Abstract Merge Sort is not working. I say this because I have tested both implementations having the same unordered list, which lead me to believe that the merge method is the one that's not working. I can't find the mistake. The private methods are in different classes. I put them here together for easier reading. Here is the code. Thank you in advance.

```
    public <T> void merge(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
//        // Merge a[lo..mid] with a[mid+1..hi].
        List<T> aux = new ArrayList<>(list);// Copy a[lo..hi] to aux[lo..hi].
        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Merge back to a[lo..hi].
            if (i > mid)
                list.set(k, aux.get(j++));
            else if (j > hi)
                list.set(k, aux.get(i++));
            else if (comparator.compare(list.get(i), list.get(j)) > 0)
                list.set(k, aux.get(j++));
            else
                list.set(k, aux.get(i++));
    }


    public <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list) {
        sort(comparator, list, 0, list.size() - 1);
    }



    //TopDown
    private <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list, int lo, int hi) {  // Sort a[lo..hi].
         if (hi <= lo) return;
         int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
         sort(comparator, list, lo, mid);       // Sort left half.
         sort(comparator, list, mid+1, hi);     // Sort right half.
         merge(comparator, list, lo, mid, hi);  // Merge results
    }

    //BottomUp
    private <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list) {
        for (int mid = 1; mid < list.size(); mid = mid + mid)
            // mid: subarray size
            for (int lo = 0; lo < list.size() - mid; lo += mid + mid) { // lo: subarray index
                merge(comparator, list, lo, lo + mid - 1, Math.min(lo + mid + mid - 1, list.size() - 1));
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is abstract merge sort?

Comment: Is the method "merge" used for both merge sorters.

Comment: Both top down and bottom up can use the same merge function. Bottom up call also needs to check if there's just a copy of the left half: merge( ... , min(lo+mid -1, list.size()-1), ... ).  It would be better to do a one time allocation of aux in the top level sort function, then pass it as a parameter to the top down or bottom up sort. The current code is allocating an entire copy of list on each merge operation which will be slow and could run out of space with a large list.

Comment: I will take into account these optimisations. However, the code is not working. I'm getting an unordered list back. Can you spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in merge() is comparing the output list elements (list) instead of the input list element (aux).

change

```
        else if (comparator.compare(list.get(i), list.get(j)) > 0)
```

to

```
        else if (comparator.compare(aux.get(i), aux.get(j)) > 0)
```

Is there a reason that merge() is not private, and that merge() and sort() are not static?